# R: Faster way of computing large distance matrix

Tags: r, geosphere

I am computing distance matrix between large number of locations (5000) on sphere  (using Haversine distance function).

Here is my code:

```
require(geosphere)
x=rnorm(5000)
y=rnorm(5000)
xy1=cbind(x,y)
```

The time taken for computing the distance matrix is

```
 system.time( outer(1:nrow(xy1), 1:nrow(xy1), function(i,j) distHaversine(xy1[i,1:2],xy1[j,1:2])))
```

The time taken to execute this program is high. Any suggestion  how to lower  time consumption to do this job! Thanks.

Comment: you can try an alternative implementation. see http://www.r-bloggers.com/computational-efficiency-of-great-circle-distance-calculations-in-r/

Comment: @Leo in good conscience and without meaning to offend I have to point out that the linked article is *terrible*! The author uses a `for` loop to cycle through a vector to repeatedly call a function (`distHaversine()`) which is already *vectorised*!! They wrote *more* code whilst also slowing the speed of execution by about 300X!!! Do not heed this article! You don't call a function 10,000 times when once will do!

Comment: Hi @SimonO'Hanlon , thanks for the heads up. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the built-in function in the `geosphere` package?

```
z <- distm( xy1 )
```

The default distance function for `distm()` - which calculates a distance matrix between a set of points - is the Haversine (`"distHaversine"`) formula, but you may specify another using the `fun` argument.

On my 2.6GHz Core i7 rMBP this takes about 5 seconds for 5,000 points.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This execution is taking less than half time than my code.

Answer (score 2):

I add below a solution using the spatialrisk package. The key functions in this package are written in C++ (Rcpp), and are therefore very fast.

```
library(geosphere)
library(spatialrisk)
library(data.table)

x=rnorm(5000)
y=rnorm(5000)
xy1 = data.table(x,y)

# Cross join two data tables
coordinates_dt <- optiRum::CJ.dt(xy1, xy1)

system.time({
  z <- distm( xy1 )
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 14.163   3.700  19.072 

system.time({
  distances_m <- coordinates_dt[, dist_m := spatialrisk::haversine(y, x, i.y, i.x)]
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 2.027   0.848   2.913
```

Comment: Can confirm, this is a very fast solution.

Comment: What about for a distance matrix of 100 million points?

Comment: If that happens, a data.frame with 1e16 rows will be generated, which is commonly referred to as 10 quadrillion:-)