# R: split-apply-combine for geographic distance

Tags: r, list, dataframe, geocoding, split-apply-combine

I have downloaded a list of all the towns and cities etc in the US from the census bureau.  Here is a random sample:

```
dput(somewhere)
structure(list(state = structure(c(30L, 31L, 5L, 31L, 24L, 36L, 
13L, 21L, 6L, 10L, 31L, 28L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 23L, 11L, 34L, 
19L, 29L, 4L, 24L, 13L, 21L, 31L, 2L, 3L, 29L, 24L, 1L, 13L, 
15L, 10L, 11L, 33L, 35L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 36L, 28L, 9L, 31L, 8L, 
14L, 11L, 12L, 36L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 29L, 8L, 7L, 23L, 25L, 39L, 
16L, 28L, 10L, 29L, 26L, 8L, 32L, 40L, 28L, 23L, 37L, 31L, 18L, 
5L, 1L, 31L, 18L, 13L, 11L, 10L, 25L, 18L, 21L, 18L, 11L, 35L, 
31L, 36L, 20L, 19L, 38L, 2L, 40L, 13L, 36L, 11L, 29L, 27L, 22L, 
17L, 12L, 20L), .Label = c("ak", "al", "ar", "az", "ca", "co", 
"fl", "ga", "hi", "ia", "il", "in", "ks", "ky", "la", "md", "mi", 
"mo", "ms", "mt", "nc", "nd", "ne", "nj", "nm", "nv", "ny", "oh", 
"ok", "or", "pa", "pr", "ri", "sc", "sd", "tx", "ut", "va", "wa", 
"wi"), class = "factor"), geoid = c(4120100L, 4280962L, 668028L, 
4243944L, 3460600L, 4871948L, 2046000L, 3747695L, 839965L, 1909910L, 
4244824L, 3902204L, 1963750L, 622360L, 669088L, 1382972L, 3125230L, 
1722736L, 4539265L, 2804705L, 4039625L, 451465L, 3467020L, 2077150L, 
3765260L, 4221792L, 133904L, 566320L, 4033150L, 3463180L, 223460L, 
2013675L, 2232405L, 1951600L, 1752142L, 4445010L, 4655684L, 1336416L, 
1729080L, 1840842L, 4804672L, 3932207L, 1523675L, 4260384L, 1321912L, 
2159232L, 1735307L, 1867176L, 4839304L, 2057350L, 1309656L, 655380L, 
4082250L, 1350680L, 1275475L, 3147745L, 3505010L, 5352285L, 2483337L, 
3909834L, 1912945L, 4068200L, 3227900L, 1366304L, 7286831L, 5505350L, 
3982390L, 3149915L, 4974480L, 4249440L, 2943346L, 677430L, 280770L, 
4247872L, 2902242L, 2039075L, 1735281L, 1932565L, 3580120L, 2973852L, 
3722620L, 2943238L, 1755938L, 4643100L, 4251904L, 4830920L, 3056575L, 
2801940L, 5156048L, 137000L, 5508925L, 2057300L, 4861172L, 1736477L, 
4021200L, 3677783L, 3832060L, 2614900L, 1820332L, 3043750L), 
    ansicode = c(2410344L, 2390453L, 2411793L, 1214759L, 885360L, 
    2412035L, 485621L, 2403359L, 2412812L, 2583481L, 2390095L, 
    2397971L, 2396237L, 2585422L, 2411819L, 2405746L, 2398338L, 
    2394628L, 2812929L, 2586582L, 2408478L, 2582836L, 885393L, 
    2397270L, 2402898L, 2584453L, 2405811L, 2405518L, 2412737L, 
    2389752L, 2418574L, 2393549L, 2402559L, 2629970L, 2399453L, 
    2378109L, 2812999L, 2402563L, 2398956L, 2396699L, 2409759L, 
    2393028L, 2414061L, 2805542L, 2404192L, 2404475L, 2398514L, 
    2629884L, 2408486L, 2396265L, 2405306L, 2411363L, 2413515L, 
    2405064L, 2402989L, 2583899L, 2629103L, 2585016L, 2390487L, 
    2397481L, 2393811L, 2413298L, 2583927L, 2812702L, 2415078L, 
    1582764L, 2400116L, 2400036L, 2412013L, 2633665L, 2787908L, 
    2583158L, 2418866L, 1214943L, 2393998L, 485611L, 2398513L, 
    2394969L, 2806756L, 2397053L, 2406485L, 2395719L, 2399572L, 
    1267480L, 2389516L, 2410660L, 2409026L, 2806379L, 2584894L, 
    2404746L, 2586459L, 2396263L, 2411528L, 2398556L, 2412443L, 
    2584298L, 1036064L, 2806333L, 2396920L, 2804282L), city = c("donald", 
    "warminster heights", "san juan capistrano", "littlestown", 
    "port republic", "taylor", "merriam", "northlakes", "julesburg", 
    "california junction", "lower allen", "antwerp", "pleasantville", 
    "el rancho", "santa clarita", "willacoochee", "kennard", 
    "effingham", "la france", "beechwood", "keys", "orange grove mobile manor", 
    "shiloh", "west mineral", "stony point", "east salem", "heath", 
    "stamps", "haworth", "rio grande", "ester", "clayton", "hackberry", 
    "middle amana", "new baden", "melville", "rolland colony", 
    "hannahs mill", "germantown hills", "la fontaine", "aurora", 
    "green meadows", "kaiminani", "pinecroft", "dawson", "park city", 
    "hinsdale", "st. meinrad", "kingsland", "powhattan", "bowersville", 
    "palos verdes estates", "wyandotte", "meigs", "waverly", 
    "sunol", "arroyo hondo", "outlook", "west pocomoke", "buchtel", 
    "chatsworth", "smith village", "glenbrook", "rock spring", 
    "villalba", "bayfield", "waynesfield", "utica", "sunset", 
    "milford square", "lithium", "swall meadows", "unalaska", 
    "martinsburg", "ashland", "leawood", "hindsboro", "gray", 
    "turley", "trimble", "falcon", "linn", "olympia fields", 
    "mitchell", "mount pleasant mills", "greenville", "park city", 
    "arkabutla", "new river", "huntsville", "boulder junction", 
    "potwin", "red lick", "huey", "dougherty", "wadsworth", "grand forks", 
    "chassell", "edgewood", "lindsay"), lsad = c("25", "57", 
    "25", "21", "25", "25", "25", "57", "43", "57", "57", "47", 
    "25", "57", "25", "25", "47", "25", "57", "57", "57", "57", 
    "21", "25", "57", "57", "43", "25", "43", "57", "57", "25", 
    "57", "57", "47", "57", "57", "57", "47", "43", "25", "57", 
    "57", "57", "25", "25", "47", "57", "57", "25", "43", "25", 
    "43", "25", "57", "57", "57", "57", "57", "47", "25", "43", 
    "57", "57", "62", "25", "47", "47", "25", "57", "57", "57", 
    "25", "21", "25", "25", "47", "25", "57", "25", "43", "25", 
    "47", "25", "57", "25", "57", "57", "57", "25", "57", "25", 
    "25", "47", "43", "57", "25", "57", "43", "57"), funcstat = c("a", 
    "s", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "a", "s", "s", "a", "a", 
    "s", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a", "s", 
    "s", "a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "a", "s", "s", "a", "s", "s", 
    "s", "a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a", "a", "s", "s", 
    "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a", 
    "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", 
    "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", 
    "a", "s", "s", "s", "a", "s", "a", "a", "a", "a", "s", "a", 
    "s", "a", "s"), latitude = c(45.221487, 40.18837, 33.500889, 
    39.74517, 39.534798, 30.573263, 39.017607, 35.780523, 40.984864, 
    41.56017, 40.226748, 41.180176, 41.387011, 36.220684, 34.414083, 
    31.335094, 41.474697, 39.120662, 34.616281, 32.336723, 35.802786, 
    32.598451, 39.462418, 37.283906, 35.867809, 40.608713, 31.344839, 
    33.354959, 33.840898, 39.019051, 64.879056, 39.736866, 29.964958, 
    41.794765, 38.536765, 41.559549, 44.3437, 32.937302, 40.768954, 
    40.673893, 33.055942, 39.867193, 19.757709, 40.564189, 31.771864, 
    37.093499, 41.800683, 38.168142, 30.666141, 39.761734, 34.373065, 
    33.774271, 36.807143, 31.071788, 27.985282, 41.154105, 36.534599, 
    46.331153, 38.096527, 39.463511, 42.916301, 35.45079, 39.100123, 
    34.81467, 18.127809, 46.81399, 40.602442, 40.895279, 41.13806, 
    40.433182, 37.831844, 37.50606, 53.910255, 40.310917, 38.812464, 
    38.907263, 39.684775, 41.841711, 36.736661, 39.476152, 35.194804, 
    38.478798, 41.521996, 43.730057, 40.724697, 33.111939, 45.630946, 
    34.700227, 37.142945, 34.782275, 46.1148, 37.938624, 33.485081, 
    38.605285, 34.399808, 42.821447, 47.921291, 47.036116, 40.103208, 
    47.224885), longitude = c(-122.837813, -75.084089, -117.654388, 
    -77.089213, -74.476099, -97.427116, -94.693955, -81.367835, 
    -102.262708, -95.994752, -76.902769, -84.736099, -93.272787, 
    -119.068357, -118.494729, -83.044003, -96.203696, -88.550859, 
    -82.770697, -90.808692, -94.941358, -114.660588, -75.29244, 
    -94.926801, -81.044121, -77.23694, -86.46905, -93.497879, 
    -94.657035, -74.87787, -148.041153, -100.176484, -93.410178, 
    -91.901539, -89.707193, -71.301933, -96.59226, -84.340945, 
    -89.462982, -85.722023, -97.509615, -83.945334, -156.001765, 
    -78.353464, -84.443499, -86.048077, -87.928172, -86.832128, 
    -98.454026, -95.634011, -83.084305, -118.425754, -94.729305, 
    -84.092683, -81.625304, -102.762746, -105.666602, -120.092812, 
    -75.579197, -82.180426, -96.514499, -97.457006, -119.927289, 
    -85.238869, -66.481897, -90.822546, -83.973881, -97.345349, 
    -112.028388, -75.405024, -89.88325, -118.642656, -166.529029, 
    -78.324286, -92.239531, -94.62524, -88.134729, -94.985863, 
    -107.792147, -94.561898, -78.65389, -91.844989, -87.691648, 
    -98.029974, -77.026451, -96.110256, -108.925311, -90.121565, 
    -80.595817, -86.532599, -89.654438, -97.01835, -94.161474, 
    -89.289973, -97.05148, -77.893875, -97.08933, -88.530745, 
    -85.737461, -105.152791), designation = c("city", "cdp", 
    "city", "borough", "city", "city", "city", "cdp", "town", 
    "cdp", "cdp", "village", "city", "cdp", "city", "city", "village", 
    "city", "cdp", "cdp", "cdp", "cdp", "borough", "city", "cdp", 
    "cdp", "town", "city", "town", "cdp", "cdp", "city", "cdp", 
    "cdp", "village", "cdp", "cdp", "cdp", "village", "town", 
    "city", "cdp", "cdp", "cdp", "city", "city", "village", "cdp", 
    "cdp", "city", "town", "city", "town", "city", "cdp", "cdp", 
    "cdp", "cdp", "cdp", "village", "city", "town", "cdp", "cdp", 
    "urbana", "city", "village", "village", "city", "cdp", "cdp", 
    "cdp", "city", "borough", "city", "city", "village", "city", 
    "cdp", "city", "town", "city", "village", "city", "cdp", 
    "city", "cdp", "cdp", "cdp", "city", "cdp", "city", "city", 
    "village", "town", "cdp", "city", "cdp", "town", "cdp")), row.names = c(22769L, 
24845L, 3314L, 24015L, 17360L, 28139L, 10085L, 19881L, 3886L, 
8750L, 24027L, 20585L, 9362L, 2499L, 3333L, 6041L, 16321L, 6847L, 
25249L, 14051L, 22233L, 1210L, 17425L, 10353L, 20053L, 23545L, 
253L, 1951L, 22166L, 17386L, 685L, 9771L, 11134L, 9225L, 7386L, 
25001L, 25862L, 5663L, 6950L, 8239L, 26555L, 20991L, 6108L, 24388L, 
5551L, 10772L, 7056L, 8470L, 27292L, 10202L, 5451L, 3116L, 22660L, 
5776L, 5317L, 16546L, 17582L, 29958L, 12103L, 20709L, 8779L, 
22515L, 16665L, 5902L, 31901L, 30658L, 21745L, 16574L, 28632L, 
24127L, 15046L, 3455L, 930L, 24087L, 14494L, 10016L, 7055L, 8993L, 
18048L, 15434L, 19615L, 15043L, 7454L, 25775L, 24194L, 27115L, 
15857L, 14038L, 29305L, 276L, 30693L, 10201L, 27863L, 7075L, 
22046L, 19267L, 20311L, 12502L, 8093L, 15798L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to calculate the distance between each entry in the `city` column using the `longitude` and `latitude` columns and the `gdist` function.  I know that the following `for` loop works and is easy to read:

```
dist_list <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(somewhere)) {
  
  dist_list[[i]] <- gdist(lon.1 = somewhere$longitude[i], 
                          lat.1 = somewhere$latitude[i], 
                          lon.2 = somewhere$longitude, 
                          lat.2 = somewhere$latitude,
                          units="miles")
  
}
```

However:  IT TAKES FOREVER to run on the full dataset (31K+ rows)--as in hours.  I'm looking for something that will speed up this calculation.  I figured something in the `split-apply-combine` approach would work well, since I would like to eventually involve a pair of grouping variables, `geo_block` and `ansi_block` but honestly anything would be better than what I have.

I have tried the following:

```
somewhere$geo_block <- substr(somewhere$geoid, 1, 1)
somewhere$ansi_block <- substr(somewhere$ansicode, 1, 1)

somewhere <- somewhere %>%
  split(.$geo_block, .$ansi_block) %>%
  mutate(dist = gdist(longlat = somewhere[, c("longitude", "latitude")]))
```

But am unsure of how to specify the second set of long-lat inputs outside of the standard `for` loop.

My question:

1. How do I use the `split-apply-combine` approach to solve this problem with `geo_block` and `ansi_block` as a grouping variable as above?  I would like to return the shortest distance and the name of the `city` and the value of `geo_block` corresponding to this distance.

All suggestions are welcome.  Ideally the desired result would be fairly quick because the actual dataset I'm working with is quite large.  Since I'm a bit in the woods here, I've added a bounty to the question to generate a little more interest and hopefully a wide set of potential answers that I can learn from. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you want every pair or distance, why are you using `state` as a grouping variable? Some states will have many many more locations than others. Instead you should use even-sized groups, say every 500 or 1000 rows.

Comment: @GregorThomas, my guess is to reduce doing an `n`-by-`n` explosion with `outer`. I'll assume that the OP doesn't care that a state boundary could easily separate closest neighbors.

Comment: That isn't what I meant ... if you have 50 locations in each of 10 states, then grouping by state means your largest calculation produces a 50x50 matrix, whereas without grouping this would create a single 500x500. Ultimately I don't know, I'm inferring.

Comment: jvalenti, I don't understand what you are expecting in your output. The pairwise distance between all points (whether grouped by `state` or not) is going to be dimensionally much larger than the number of rows, so it will not fit cleanly into a frame. Do you want the closest? A statistic of distances? If grouping by `state`, do you care that two locations may be separated by feet but will not be paired?

Comment: Yes, that's my assumption too. But I think state is a bad grouper there - California or Texas probably has many many more locations than Wyoming. It would be safer to put more precise bounds and just group by every 50 rows rather than whatever variable number of locations are in each state.

Comment: Strongly related question: [Faster way of computing large distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37407065/903061). Don't know how efficient `gdist` is, but one answer there shows that `spatialrisk::haversine` is an order of magnitude faster than `geosphere::distm`.

Comment: @r2evans, I have specified my desired result and narrowed my question.  Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: As for distance-calculation, I haven't benchmarked it, but while the Haversine calculation is significantly faster, it is also less accurate with smaller distances. More accuracy is had with Vincenty (spheroid) or even better with Vincenty ellipsoid, at the expense of calculation time. (It really isn't that big, though, I use the latter on 2M rows regularly.) Over to you and the quality of input and expected output accuracy.

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59915415/2761575 for fast and memory-efficient method to create dist from lat-long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll show both the tidyverse and base R approaches to split-apply-combine. My understanding is that, for each city in each group of cities (whatever your grouping variables may be), you want to report the nearest within-group city and the distance to that nearest city.

First, a couple of remarks about `Imap::gdist`:

- It does not have a `lonlat` argument. You must use the arguments `(lon|lat).(1|2)` to pass coordinates.
- It may not be vectorized properly. Its body contains a loop `while (abs(lamda - lamda.old) > 1e-11) {...}`, where the value of `lamda` is `(lon.1 - lon.2) * pi / 180`. For the loop condition to have length 1 (it should), the arguments `lon.1` and `lon.2` must have length 1.

So, at least for now, I'll base my answer on the more canonical `geosphere::distm`. It stores the entire `n`-by-`n` symmetric distance matrix in memory, so you may hit a memory allocation limit, but that is much less likely to happen within a split-apply-combine, where `n` is the within-group (rather than total) number of cities.

I'll be working with this part of your data frame:

```r
library("dplyr")

dd <- somewhere %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(geo_block = as.factor(as.integer(substr(geoid, 1L, 1L))),
         ansi_block = as.factor(as.integer(substr(ansicode, 1L, 1L)))) %>%
  select(geo_block, ansi_block, city, longitude, latitude)
dd
# # A tibble: 100 × 5
#    geo_block ansi_block city                longitude latitude
#    <fct>     <fct>      <chr>                   <dbl>    <dbl>
#  1 4         2          donald                 -123.      45.2
#  2 4         2          warminster heights      -75.1     40.2
#  3 6         2          san juan capistrano    -118.      33.5
#  4 4         1          littlestown             -77.1     39.7
#  5 3         8          port republic           -74.5     39.5
#  6 4         2          taylor                  -97.4     30.6
#  7 2         4          merriam                 -94.7     39.0
#  8 3         2          northlakes              -81.4     35.8
#  9 8         2          julesburg              -102.      41.0
# 10 1         2          california junction     -96.0     41.6
# # … with 90 more rows
```

The following function `find_nearest` performs the basic task of identifying nearest neighbours given a set of `n` points in a `d`-dimensional metric space. Its arguments are as follows:

1. `data`: A data frame with `n` rows (one per point), `d` variables
   specifying point coordinates, and 1 or more ID variables to be
   associated with each point.
2. `dist`: A function taking an `n`-by-`d` matrix of coordinates as
   an argument and returning a corresponding `n`-by-`n` symmetric
   distance matrix.
3. `coordvar`: A character vector listing coordinate variable names.
4. `idvar`: A character vector listing ID variable names.

In our data frame, the coordinate variables are `longitude` and `latitude` and there is one ID variable `city`. For simplicity, I have defined the default values of `coordvar` and `idvar` accordingly.

```r
find_nearest <- function(data, dist, 
                         coordvar = c("longitude", "latitude"), 
                         idvar = "city") {
  m <- match(coordvar, names(data), 0L)
  n <- nrow(data)
  if (n < 2L) {
    argmin <- NA_integer_[n]
    distance <- NA_real_[n]
  } else {
    ## Compute distance matrix
    D <- dist(as.matrix(data[m]))
    ## Extract minimum distances
    diag(D) <- Inf # want off-diagonal distances
    argmin <- apply(D, 2L, which.min)
    distance <- D[cbind(argmin, seq_len(n))]
  }
  ## Return focal point data, nearest neighbour ID, distance
  r1 <- data[-m]
  r2 <- data[argmin, idvar, drop = FALSE]
  names(r2) <- paste0(idvar, "_nearest")
  data.frame(r1, r2, distance, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Here is the output of `find_nearest` applied to our data frame, without grouping, with distances computed by the Vincenty ellipsoid method.

```r
dist_vel <- function(x) {
  geosphere::distm(x, fun = geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid)
}

res <- find_nearest(dd, dist = dist_vel)
head(res, 10L)
#    geo_block ansi_block                city         city_nearest  distance
# 1          4          2              donald              outlook 246536.39
# 2          4          2  warminster heights       milford square  38512.79
# 3          6          2 san juan capistrano palos verdes estates  77722.35
# 4          4          1         littlestown          lower allen  55792.53
# 5          3          8       port republic           rio grande  66935.70
# 6          4          2              taylor            kingsland  98997.90
# 7          2          4             merriam              leawood  13620.87
# 8          3          2          northlakes          stony point  30813.46
# 9          8          2           julesburg                sunol  46037.81
# 10         1          2 california junction              kennard  19857.41
```

Here is the tidyverse split-apply-combine, grouping on `geo_block` and `ansi_block`:

```r
dd %>%
  group_by(geo_block, ansi_block) %>%
  group_modify(~find_nearest(., dist = dist_vel))
# # A tibble: 100 × 5
# # Groups:   geo_block, ansi_block [13]
#    geo_block ansi_block city                city_nearest  distance
#    <fct>     <fct>      <chr>               <chr>            <dbl>
#  1 1         2          california junction gray            89610.
#  2 1         2          pleasantville       middle amana   122974.
#  3 1         2          willacoochee        meigs          104116.
#  4 1         2          effingham           hindsboro       72160.
#  5 1         2          heath               dawson         198052.
#  6 1         2          middle amana        pleasantville  122974.
#  7 1         2          new baden           huey            37147.
#  8 1         2          hannahs mill        dawson         129599.
#  9 1         2          germantown hills    hindsboro      165140.
# 10 1         2          la fontaine         edgewood        63384.
# # … with 90 more rows
```

Note, for example, how the city considered nearest to California Junction changes from Kennard to Gray, which is farther away, under this grouping.

Here is the base R split-apply-combine, built on base function `by`. It is equivalent except for the ordering of groups in the result:

```r
find_nearest_by <- function(data, by, ...) {
  do.call(rbind, base::by(data, by, find_nearest, ...))
}

res <- find_nearest_by(dd, by = dd[c("geo_block", "ansi_block")], dist = dist_vel)
head(res, 10L)
#    geo_block ansi_block                city city_nearest   distance
# 1          3          1         grand forks         <NA>         NA
# 2          4          1         littlestown  martinsburg  122718.95
# 3          4          1         martinsburg  littlestown  122718.95
# 4          4          1            mitchell  martinsburg 1671365.58
# 5          5          1            bayfield         <NA>         NA
# 6          1          2 california junction         gray   89609.71
# 7          1          2       pleasantville middle amana  122974.32
# 8          1          2        willacoochee        meigs  104116.21
# 9          1          2           effingham    hindsboro   72160.43
# 10         1          2               heath       dawson  198051.76
```

This ordering reveals that `find_nearest` returns `NA` for groups containing only one city. We would have seen these `NA` in the tidyverse result had we printed the entire tibble.

FWIW, here is a benchmark of the various functions implemented in `geosphere` for computing geodesic distances, saying nothing about accuracy, though you can speculate from the results that the Vincenty ellipsoid distance cuts the fewest corners (haha)...

```r
fn <- function(dist) find_nearest(dd, dist = dist)

library("geosphere")
dist_geo <- function(x) distm(x, fun = distGeo)
dist_cos <- function(x) distm(x, fun = distCosine)
dist_hav <- function(x) distm(x, fun = distHaversine)
dist_vsp <- function(x) distm(x, fun = distVincentySphere)
dist_vel <- function(x) distm(x, fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)
dist_mee <- function(x) distm(x, fun = distMeeus)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fn(dist_geo),
  fn(dist_cos),
  fn(dist_hav),
  fn(dist_vsp),
  fn(dist_vel),
  fn(dist_mee),
  times = 1000L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
#  fn(dist_geo)   6.143276   6.291737   6.718329   6.362257   6.459345  45.91131  1000
#  fn(dist_cos)   4.239236   4.399977   4.918079   4.461804   4.572033  45.70233  1000
#  fn(dist_hav)   4.005331   4.156067   4.641016   4.210721   4.307542  41.91619  1000
#  fn(dist_vsp)   3.827227   3.979829   4.446428   4.033621   4.123924  44.29160  1000
#  fn(dist_vel) 129.712069 132.549638 135.006170 133.935479 135.248135 174.88874  1000
#  fn(dist_mee)   3.716814   3.830999   4.234231   3.883582   3.962712  42.12947  1000
```

`Imap::gdist` seems to be a pure R implementation of Vincenty ellipsoid distance. That may account for its slowness...

Some final remarks:

- The `dist` argument of `find_nearest` need not be built on one of the `geosphere` distances. You can pass any function you want satisfying the constraints that I state above.
- `find_nearest` could be adapted to accept functions `dist` returning objects of class `"dist"`. These objects store just the `n*(n-1)/2` lower triangular elements of the `n`-by-`n` symmetric distance matrix (see `?dist`). This would improve support for large `n` and make `find_nearest` compatible with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907035/memory-efficient-method-to-create-dist-object-from-distance-matrix/59915415#59915415) memory-efficient implementation of the Haversine distance (suggested by @dww in the comments). It would just need to be worked out how to translate an operation like `apply(D, 2L, which.min)`. [Update: I have implemented this change to `find_nearest` in [a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69968683/12685768), where I provide new benchmarks.]

Comment: this works pretty well.  One more question:  How would I add another variable from `somewhere` that corresponds to the `city_nearest`, for example `lsad`.  I tried using the `idvar[lsad]` in the `names(d2)` but received the error:  `A points matrix should have 2 columns`.

Comment: `idvar` can be any subset of `names(data)`. If you do `res <- find_nearest(data, dist, idvar = c("city", "lsad"))`, with `data` containing both `city` and `lsad` (in addition to `longitude` and `latitude`), then `res` should contain `city_nearest` and `lsad_nearest`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make `find_nearest` slightly more general and potentially more useful to others. The change doesn't break any of the code in the answer. (I've just replaced the arguments `lonvar` and `latvar` with a single argument `coordvar`.)

Comment: How do I get the row index of `city_nearest` , accounting for groups?

Comment: Is this what you mean? `dd %>% mutate(row = seq_len(nrow(.))) %>% group_by(geo_block, ansi_block) %>% group_modify(~find_nearest(., dist = dist_vel, idvar = "row"))`

Comment: There, `row` and `row_nearest` index the rows of `dd` (and in turn the rows of `somewhere`).

Comment: that generates an error message when used on full data:  `Error:  problem with mutate() on column row`.

Comment: I don't see an error when I run `dd %>% mutate(row = seq_len(nrow(.))) %>% find_nearest(dist = dist_vel, idvar = "row")`, which applies `find_nearest` without grouping. Are you doing something differently?

Comment: It might be worth trying `find_nearest2` from my other answer. On my machine, it is able to processes 40000 longitude-latitude pairs in less than two minutes, even without a split-apply-combine.

Comment: thank you for your thorough and thoughtful answers to my question.  I learned a lot from your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very similar to [R: Faster way of computing large distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407065/r-faster-way-of-computing-large-distance-matrix). One option is to use spatialrisk::haversine():

```r
library(spatialrisk)
library(data.table)
library(optiRum)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.3, PROJ 7.2.1
library(s2)

# Create data.table
s_dt = data.table::data.table(city = somewhere$city,
                              x = somewhere$latitude, 
                              y = somewhere$longitude)

# Cross join two data tables
coordinates_dt <- optiRum::CJ.dt(s_dt, s_dt)
distance_m <- coordinates_dt[, dist_m := spatialrisk::haversine(y, x, i.y, i.x)][
  dist_m > 0, .SD[which.min(dist_m)], by = .(city, x, y)]
head(distance_m)
#>                   city        x          y               i.city      i.x
#> 1:  warminster heights 40.18837  -75.08409               shiloh 39.46242
#> 2: san juan capistrano 33.50089 -117.65439 palos verdes estates 33.77427
#> 3:         littlestown 39.74517  -77.08921          lower allen 40.22675
#> 4:       port republic 39.53480  -74.47610           rio grande 39.01905
#> 5:              taylor 30.57326  -97.42712               aurora 33.05594
#> 6:             merriam 39.01761  -94.69396              leawood 38.90726
#>           i.y    dist_m
#> 1:  -75.29244 31059.909
#> 2: -118.42575 87051.444
#> 3:  -76.90277 24005.689
#> 4:  -74.87787 47227.822
#> 5:  -97.50961 37074.461
#> 6:  -94.62524  7714.126
```

You can also use the wonderful `sf` package. For example sf::st_nearest_feature() gives:

```r
s_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(s_dt, coords = c("x", "y"))
cities <- sf::st_as_sfc(s2::as_s2_geography(s_sf))
s_dt$city_nearest <-  s_dt$city[sf::st_nearest_feature(cities)]
```

Compare speed of both methods:

```r
method_1 <- function(){
  coordinates_dt[, dist_m := spatialrisk::haversine(y, x, i.y, i.x)][
    dist_m > 0, .SD[which.min(dist_m)], by = .(city, x, y)]
}

method_2 <- function(){
  s_dt$city[sf::st_nearest_feature(cities)]
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  method_1(), 
  method_2(), 
  times = 100
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max
#>  method_1()   5.385391   5.652444   6.234329   5.772923   6.003445  11.60981
#>  method_2() 182.730850 188.408202 203.348667 199.049937 211.682795 303.14904
#>  neval
#>    100
#>    100
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the remark that I left at the end of [my initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69951592/12685768), I thought I'd share a more robust version of `find_nearest` that also accepts functions `dist` returning objects of class `"dist"`. These objects are double vectors storing only the `n*(n-1)/2` non-redundant elements of an `n`-by-`n` distance matrix (see `?dist`). When we work with `"dist"` objects instead of matrices, the maximum number of longitude-latitude pairs that we can consider at once without hitting a memory limit increases from `N` to roughly `sqrt(2)*N`.

If you skip to the end, then you'll find that using `find_nearest2` in conjunction with @dww's fast `calc_dist` function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907035/memory-efficient-method-to-create-dist-object-from-distance-matrix/59915415#59915415)), which returns `"dist"` objects, allows me to process `n = 40000` ungrouped longitude-latitude pairs in less than two minutes.

`find_nearest2` hinges on the existence of a subset method for class `"dist"` that operates on `"dist"` objects `x` like the corresponding  matrices, *without* constructing those matrices. More precisely, `x[i, j]` should return the value of `as.matrix(x)[i, j]` without constructing `as.matrix(x)`. Fortunately, for our purposes, this optimization is only necessary in two special cases: (i) column extraction and (ii) element extraction with matrix indices.

```r
`[.dist` <- function(x, i, j, drop = TRUE) {
  class(x) <- NULL
  p <- length(x)
  n <- as.integer(round(0.5 * (1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * p)))) # p = n * (n - 1) / 2
  
  ## Column extraction
  if (missing(i) && !missing(j) && is.integer(j) && length(j) == 1L && !is.na(j) && j >= 1L && j <= n) {
    if (j == 1L) {
      return(c(0, x[seq_len(n - 1L)]))
    }
    ## Convert 2-ary index of 'D' to 1-ary index of 'D[lower.tri(D)]'
    ii <- rep.int(j - 1L, j - 1L)
    jj <- 1L:(j - 1L)
    if (j < n) {
      ii <- c(ii, j:(n - 1L))
      jj <- c(jj, rep.int(j, n - j))
    }
    kk <- ii + round(0.5 * (2L * (n - 1L) - jj) * (jj - 1L))
    ## Extract
    res <- double(n)
    res[-j] <- x[kk]
    nms <- attr(x, "Labels")
    if (drop) {
      names(res) <- nms
    } else {
      dim(res) <- c(n, 1L)
      dimnames(res) <- list(nms, nms[j])
    }
    return(res)
  }
  
  ## Element extraction with matrix indices
  if (missing(j) && !missing(i) && is.matrix(i) && dim(i)[2L] == 2L && is.integer(i) && !anyNA(i) && all(i >= 1L & i <= n)) {
    m <- dim(i)[1L]
    ## Subset off-diagonal entries
    d <- i[, 1L] == i[, 2L]
    i <- i[!d, , drop = FALSE]
    ## Transpose upper triangular entries
    u <- i[, 2L] > i[, 1L]
    i[u, 1:2] <- i[u, 2:1]
    ## Convert 2-ary index of 'D' to 1-ary index of 'D[lower.tri(D)]'
    ii <- i[, 1L] - 1L
    jj <- i[, 2L]
    kk <- ii + (jj > 1L) * round(0.5 * (2L * (n - 1L) - jj) * (jj - 1L))
    ## Extract
    res <- double(m)
    res[!d] <- x[kk] 
    return(res)
  }

  ## Fall back on coercion for any other subset operation
  as.matrix(x)[i, j, drop = drop]
}
```

Here is a simple test.

```r
n <- 6L
do <- dist(seq_len(n))
dm <- unname(as.matrix(do))
ij <- cbind(sample(6L), sample(6L))
identical(do[, 4L], dm[, 4L]) # TRUE
identical(do[ij], dm[ij]) # TRUE
```

And here is `find_nearest2`. Note instances where the subset operator `[` is applied to object `D`. Due to the optimizations in our subset method, none of these involve coercion from `"dist"` to `"matrix"`.

```r
find_nearest2 <- function(data, dist, coordvar, idvar) {
  m <- match(coordvar, names(data), 0L)
  n <- nrow(data)
  if (n < 2L) {
    argmin <- NA_integer_[n]
    distance <- NA_real_[n]
  } else {
    ## Compute distance matrix
    D <- dist(data[m])
    ## Extract minimum off-diagonal distances
    patch.which.min <- function(x, i) {
      x[i] <- Inf
      which.min(x)
    }
    argmin <- integer(n)
    index <- seq_len(n)
    for (j in index) {
      argmin[j] <- forceAndCall(2L, patch.which.min, D[, j], j)
    }
    distance <- D[cbind(argmin, index)]
  }
  ## Return focal point data, nearest neighbour ID, distance
  r1 <- data[-m]
  r2 <- data[argmin, idvar, drop = FALSE]
  names(r2) <- paste0(idvar, "_nearest")
  data.frame(r1, r2, distance, row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Let's source @dww's C++ code so that `calc_dist` is available in our R session.

```r
code <- '#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

double distanceHaversine(double latf, double lonf, double latt, double lont, double tolerance) {
  double d;
  double dlat = latt - latf;
  double dlon =  lont - lonf;
  d = (sin(dlat * 0.5) * sin(dlat * 0.5)) + (cos(latf) * cos(latt)) * (sin(dlon * 0.5) * sin(dlon * 0.5));
  if(d > 1 && d <= tolerance){
    d = 1;
  }
  return 2 * atan2(sqrt(d), sqrt(1 - d)) * 6378137.0;
}

double toRadians(double deg){
  return deg * 0.01745329251;  // PI / 180;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector calc_dist(Rcpp::NumericVector lat, 
                        Rcpp::NumericVector lon, 
                        double tolerance = 10000000000.0) {
  std::size_t nlat = lat.size();
  std::size_t nlon = lon.size();
  if (nlat != nlon) throw std::range_error("lat and lon different lengths");
  if (nlat < 2) throw std::range_error("Need at least 2 points");
  std::size_t size = nlat * (nlat - 1) / 2;
  NumericVector ans(size);
  std::size_t k = 0;
  double latf;
  double latt;
  double lonf;
  double lont;
  
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < (nlat-1); j++) {
    for (std::size_t i = j + 1; i < nlat; i++) {
      latf = toRadians(lat[i]);
      lonf = toRadians(lon[i]);
      latt = toRadians(lat[j]);
      lont = toRadians(lon[j]);
      ans[k++] = distanceHaversine(latf, lonf, latt, lont, tolerance);
    }
  }
  
  return ans;
}
'
Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = code)
```

And let's compare the performance of `find_nearest2` for `n` equal to 100, 20000, and 40000, and for two functions `dist`, one using `geosphere::distm` to construct a full distance matrix and the other using @dww's `calc_dist` to construct a `"dist"` object. Both functions compute Haversine distances.

```
rx <- function(n) {
  data.frame(id = seq_len(n), lon = rnorm(n), lat = rnorm(n))
}
dist_hav <- function(x) {
  geosphere::distm(x, fun = geosphere::distHaversine)
}
dist_dww <- function(x) {
  res <- calc_dist(x[, 2L], x[, 1L])
  attr(res, "class") <- "dist"
  attr(res, "Size") <- nrow(x)
  attr(res, "Diag") <- FALSE
  attr(res, "Upper") <- FALSE
  attr(res, "call") <- match.call()
  res
}
```

Here is the benchmark:

```
fn2 <- function(data, dist) {
  find_nearest2(data, dist = dist, coordvar = c("lon", "lat"), idvar = "id")
}

x1 <- rx(100L)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fn2(x1, dist_hav), 
  fn2(x1, dist_dww), 
  times = 1000L
)
# Unit: microseconds
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  fn2(x1, dist_hav) 3768.310 3886.452 4680.300 3977.492 4131.796 34461.361  1000
#  fn2(x1, dist_dww)  930.044  992.241 1128.272 1017.005 1045.746  7006.326  1000

x2 <- rx(20000L)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fn2(x2, dist_hav),
  fn2(x2, dist_dww),
  times = 100L
)
# Unit: seconds
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  fn2(x2, dist_hav) 29.60596 30.04249 30.29052 30.14016 30.45054 31.53976   100
#  fn2(x2, dist_dww) 18.71327 19.01204 19.12311 19.09058 19.26680 19.62273   100

x3 <- rx(40000L)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  # fn2(x3, dist_hav), # runs out of memory
  fn2(x3, dist_dww),
  times = 10L
)
# Unit: seconds
#               expr      min      lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
#  fn2(x3, dist_dww) 104.8912 105.762 109.1512 109.653 112.2543 112.9265    10
```

So, at least on my machine, `find_nearest2(dist = dist_dww)` would complete in less than two minutes without running out of memory if applied to your full, ungrouped data set (`n` around 32000).

Answer (score 0):

I have such a solution. And I'm surprised myself that I used two loops `for`!! Incredibly, I did it. First things first.

My proposal is based on a simplification. However, the mistake you will make at short distances will be relatively small. But the time gain is huge!

Well, I propose to count the distance in Cartesian coordinates, not spherical.

So we're going to need a simple function that computes the Cartesian coordinates based on the two arguments `latitude` and `longitude`.
Here is our `LatLong2Cart` feature.

```
LatLong2Cart = function(latitude, longitude, REarth = 6371) { 
  tibble(
    x = REarth * cos(latitude) * cos(longitude),
    y = REarth * cos(latitude) * sin(longitude),
    z = REarth *sin(latitude))
}
```

A short comment right away, my function counts distances in kilometers (after all, it's SI units). If you want you can change it by entering the radius in any other units of miles, yards, feet or whatever else you want.

Let's see how it works. But let me convert yoours `data.frame` to `tibble` first.

```
library(tidyverse)
somewhere = somewhere %>% as_tibble()

somewhere %>%  
  mutate(LatLong2Cart(latitude, longitude))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 12
   state   geoid ansicode city                lsad  funcstat latitude longitude designation      x      y      z
   <fct>   <int>    <int> <chr>               <chr> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 or    4120100  2410344 donald              25    a            45.2    -123.  city        -1972.   644.  6024.
 2 pa    4280962  2390453 warminster heights  57    s            40.2     -75.1 cdp         -4815. -1564.  3867.
 3 ca     668028  2411793 san juan capistrano 25    a            33.5    -118.  city          485. -3096.  5547.
 4 pa    4243944  1214759 littlestown         21    a            39.7     -77.1 borough       350.  2894.  5665.
 5 nj    3460600   885360 port republic       25    a            39.5     -74.5 city        -1008. -1329.  6149.
 6 tx    4871948  2412035 taylor              25    a            30.6     -97.4 city        -4237.   160. -4755.
 7 ks    2046000   485621 merriam             25    a            39.0     -94.7 city         1435.  -686.  6169.
 8 nc    3747695  2403359 northlakes          57    s            35.8     -81.4 cdp         -2066.  -670. -5990.
 9 co     839965  2412812 julesburg           43    a            41.0    -102.  town         1010.  6223.  -915.
10 ia    1909910  2583481 california junction 57    s            41.6     -96.0 cdp           840.  4718. -4198.
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Once we have the Cartesian coordinates, let's calculate the appropriate distances. I prepared the `calcDist` function for this purpose.

```
calcDist = function(data, key){
  if(!all(c("x", "y", "z") %in% names(data))) {
    stop("date must contain the variables x, y and z!")
  }
  key=enquo(key)
  n = nrow(data)
  dist = array(data = as.double(0), dim=n*n)
  x = data$x
  y = data$y
  z = data$z
  keys = data %>% pull(!!key)
  for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
      dist[i+(j-1)*n] = sqrt((x[i]-x[j])^2+(y[i]-y[j])^2+(z[i]-z[j])^2)
    }
  }
  tibble(
    expand.grid(factor(keys), factor(keys)),
    dist = dist
    )
}
```

This is the place anyway. Right here I used these two `for` loops. **I hope to be forgiven for that!**

Well, let's see if these loops can do something there.

```
somewhere %>%  
  mutate(LatLong2Cart(latitude, longitude)) %>% 
  calcDist(city)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10,000 x 3
   Var1                Var2     dist
   <fct>               <fct>   <dbl>
 1 donald              donald     0 
 2 warminster heights  donald  4197.
 3 san juan capistrano donald  4500.
 4 littlestown         donald  3253.
 5 port republic       donald  2200.
 6 taylor              donald 11025.
 7 merriam             donald  3660.
 8 northlakes          donald 12085.
 9 julesburg           donald  9390.
10 california junction donald 11358.
# ... with 9,990 more rows
```

As you can see, everything works great. Okay, but how to use it on grouped data? It's nothing hard. Let's group it by states.

```
somewhere %>% 
  mutate(LatLong2Cart(latitude, longitude)) %>% 
  nest_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(dist = list(calcDist(data, city))) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest(dist)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 400 x 4
# Groups:   state [40]
   state Var1                      Var2                        dist
   <fct> <fct>                     <fct>                      <dbl>
 1 ak    ester                     ester                         0 
 2 ak    unalaska                  ester                      9245.
 3 ak    ester                     unalaska                   9245.
 4 ak    unalaska                  unalaska                      0 
 5 al    heath                     heath                         0 
 6 al    huntsville                heath                     12597.
 7 al    heath                     huntsville                12597.
 8 al    huntsville                huntsville                    0 
 9 ar    stamps                    stamps                        0 
10 az    orange grove mobile manor orange grove mobile manor     0 
# ... with 390 more rows
```

There is maybe a small redundancy of data here (there are distances from city A to city B and from city B to city A) but the whole thing is relatively easy to implement, which you will probably admit yourself.

Ok. Now it's time to see how it will work when we group as you want by `geo_block` and `ansi_block`.

```
somewhere %>% 
  mutate(LatLong2Cart(latitude, longitude)) %>% 
  mutate(
    geo_block = substr(geoid, 1, 1),
    ansi_block = substr(ansicode, 1, 1)) %>% 
  nest_by(geo_block, ansi_block) %>% 
  mutate(dist = list(calcDist(data, city))) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest(dist)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1,716 x 5
# Groups:   geo_block, ansi_block [13]
   geo_block ansi_block Var1                Var2                  dist
   <chr>     <chr>      <fct>               <fct>                <dbl>
 1 1         2          california junction california junction     0 
 2 1         2          pleasantville       california junction 10051.
 3 1         2          willacoochee        california junction 11545.
 4 1         2          effingham           california junction 11735.
 5 1         2          heath               california junction  4097.
 6 1         2          middle amana        california junction  7618.
 7 1         2          new baden           california junction 12720.
 8 1         2          hannahs mill        california junction 11681.
 9 1         2          germantown hills    california junction  5097.
10 1         2          la fontaine         california junction 11397.
# ... with 1,706 more rows
```

As you can see, there is no problem with that.

Finally, a practical note. When you use this solution, make sure that the grouped variables are not longer than about 20,000 lines. This can lead to memory allocation problems for such large data. Note that then your result will be 20,000 * 20,000 lines which is quite a lot and you may run out of memory at some point. Although the calculations should not take more than a minute.

Please check how it works on your data and give some feedback. I also hope that you liked my solution and that the error of distance resulting from the calculations in Cartesian coordinates will not bother you in any particular way.